# Arduino MPU6050 AD0 Tricks with offset setting gives corrupted data

Tags: c++, mpu6050

I am currently experimenting with two MPU6050 which the AD0 is connected via PIN 7 and PIN 8 respectively, and if this is working, I plan to add another 2 more MPU6050 to it.

I am using i2cdevlib's MPU6050 library and what I did in a flow is:

1. Initialize one MPU6050 object
2. Set MPU6050 Object as 0x68 (LOW AD0)
3. Set all to HIGH, but one to LOW (to select the MPU6050)
4. Calculate offset and calibrate, store everything in array. (offsets and etc)
5. Repeat steps 3 to 4 unless all are calibrated.
6. Start to loop between two MPU, setting everything to HIGH and the one to be used as low.
7. Write the LOW's (current selected) MPU with offset that is stored in array, then getMotion6 (Raw data).
8. Write selected MPU to high, repeat from step 6 to step 7.

Everything is working, however when I am having a loop to collect data, it gives me corrupted data, the problem I find is in this function

```
void loop{
    for (int i = 7; i <= 8; i++) {
      pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

      digitalWrite( i, LOW);
      //      Serial.print("\nWriting pin: ");
      //      Serial.print(i);
      //      Serial.println(" to LOW");
      delay(2);
      int index = i - 7;
      Serial.print("Offsets:\t");
      Serial.print(ax_offset[index]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(ay_offset[index]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(az_offset[index]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(gx_offset[index]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(gy_offset[index]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.println(gz_offset[index]);

      accelgyro.setXAccelOffset(ax_offset[index]);
      accelgyro.setYAccelOffset(ay_offset[index]);
      accelgyro.setZAccelOffset(az_offset[index]);
      accelgyro.setXGyroOffset(gx_offset[index]);
      accelgyro.setYGyroOffset(gy_offset[index]);
      accelgyro.setZGyroOffset(gz_offset[index]);

      Serial.print(accelgyro.getXAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(accelgyro.getYAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(accelgyro.getZAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(accelgyro.getXGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(accelgyro.getYGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(accelgyro.getZGyroOffset()); Serial.println("\t");

      //      delay(1000);
      //      accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax[index], &ay[index], &az[index], &gx[index], &gy[index], &gz[index]);
      int ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;
      accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

      Serial.print("PIN ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print("'s data is:");
      Serial.print("aX:" ); Serial.print(ax); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("aY:" ); Serial.print(ay); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("aZ:" ); Serial.print(az); Serial.print("\t");

      Serial.print("gX:" ); Serial.print(gx); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("gY:" ); Serial.print(gy); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("gZ:" ); Serial.println(gz);

      pinMode(i, INPUT_PULLUP);
    }
}
```

The first few loops will return accurate data (as in, all the sensors are close 0 [no motion])

I am suspecting because there is a huge difference between both sensors and the getMotion6 is comparing with the old sensor, can that be the case?

Attached is the output of my sensors reading, untouched.

[image]